Custom interactive container with zoom and pan – focal point shifts initially, and panning doesn’t work
I am trying to create an interactive container in Flutter that supports zooming and panning. However, I cannot use the InteractiveViewer widget due to specific need of my application, so I'm creating my own implementation.
Desired behavior:

Zoom into the container while keeping the focal point in place.
Allow smooth panning of the container.

Issue:
The current code can zoom and maintain the focal point during zooming, but the focal point shifts at the start of zooming. Additionally, panning is not smooth. I've tried many different formulas for the _offset, and this is my closest attempt so far:
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:fa_simulator/config/config.dart';
import 'package:fa_simulator/widget/body/body_singleton.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InteractiveContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const InteractiveContainer({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  State<InteractiveContainer> createState() {
    return _InteractiveContainerState();
  }
}

class _InteractiveContainerState extends State<InteractiveContainer> {
  double _scale = 1;
  double _previousScale = 1;
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;
  Offset _previousOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset _center = Offset.zero;

  final GlobalKey _overflowBoxKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails details) {
        _previousScale = _scale;
        _previousOffset = details.focalPoint - _offset;
        _center = (Offset(bodySize.width / 2, bodySize.height / 2)) -
            BodySingleton().getBodyLocalPosition(details.focalPoint);
        //Local position of the entire interactive container
        //Using key of the child
      },
      onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
        setState(() {
          _scale = _previousScale * details.scale;
          _offset =
              (details.focalPoint - _previousOffset) + (_center * (_scale - 1));
        });
      },
      onScaleEnd: (ScaleEndDetails details) {
        _previousScale = 1.0;
        _previousOffset = Offset.zero;
        _center = Offset.zero;
      },
      child: OverflowBox(
        key: _overflowBoxKey,
        maxWidth: double.infinity,
        maxHeight: double.infinity,
        child: Transform(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..translate(_offset.dx, _offset.dy)
            ..scale(_scale),
          child: widget.child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Questions:

How can I fix the issue where the focal point shifts at the start of zooming?
How can I implement panning so it works smoothly?

